# How do I remove 4 pieces of tile in my shower?

Tags: shower

I am replacing my old 3 piece grohe faucets with a one-piece shower faucet.  I need to remove 4 tiles, which will be replaced when the new faucet is installed.

How can I remove the 4 tiles without damaging the tiles I want to keep? I don't want to buy a specialty saw for just a one-time job.

Thank you!

Comment: Please revise to tell us something about the tiles in question.

Answer (score 2):

You first cut the grout line surrounding the 4 tiles.  The cheapest tool for that task is a $10 grout saw like this https://www.lowes.com/pd/Marshalltown-2-in-Steel-Blade-Red-Plastic-Grout-Saw/1000204021.  You can remove easily 5 ft of grout line in 30 minutes with this tool and elbow grease.

Then use a drill make holes in your tiles.  Use a hammer and gently tap on the tiles.  Finally, cleanup the thinset left behind.

Comment: Make CERTAIN you remove ALL thinset on underlayment or setting new tiles will be a huge problem.

Comment: The plumber is going to entire remove the old four tiles where I have two handles and a 'thing' that I turn for either a shower or bath.  That has totally seized up, as well as the two handles.  I decided to get the new one-piece up-to-date piece, so he will be removing the backer board or what might be there.   I think I might try and dremel and the grout saw recommended above.  MUCH THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!!!!!

Comment: @Anna if you need to redo the plumbing, you have to remove whatever that the tiles are attached to. Usually it is a cement board. By the way, what are you using to replace the removed tiles? Do you have any spare? The thing that turns from shower to bath is a diverter. It redirects water into one of your pipes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies.  I bought the Marshalltown grout saw yesterday and will attempt to remove the grout tomorrow.. I don't know what is in the back of the tile..,green board? backer board, ?  I don't have replacement tiles, so might use decorative tiles that are compatible in color. I tiled my other bathroom by myself, so might try to do it again when I see what the plumber will uncover on Thursday,  Yes, diverter!!!!  I totally forgot what it is called!!!!

Comment: cool.  glad you already have a plan for repairing the tiles.  when using the saw, dip the blade in water after few strokes.  works better wet.  just like wet saws.